# Plymouth boot splash stretched with widescreen monitor

Tags: display, plymouth

I just upgraded from a monitor of 1680×1050 to a new one with 1920x1080 screen size.

The elementary logo is now stretched. I've tried "sudo update-initramfs -u" and "sudo update-grub2" without avail.

Any idea what to do?